# Provided column already belongs to the DataGridView control. error

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 2 DATAGRIDVIEWS and select data into it ,

I am getting this error when I type the order number and hit ENTER for the second time ,

for example when type the order number = 200 and hit ENTER the data selected into DATAGRIDVIEWS ,
but when I type another order number for example 220 and hit ENTER key I got this error on this line of code :

```
dgvSampleDetails.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxselect);
```

This is my code and what I tried :

```
private void txtOrder_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
              
                   // this.dgvSampleDetails.Rows.Clear();
                   // this.dgvSampleDetails.Columns.Clear();
                    dgvOrderDetails.DataSource = sample.SearchOrders1(txtOrder.Text);
                    dgvSampleDetails.DataSource = sample.GetOrderSamples(txtOrder.Text);
                    btnSave.Enabled = true;
                    dgvSampleDetails.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxselect);
                    checkboxselect.HeaderText = "Select";
                    checkboxselect.Name = "select";

                }
        }
```

How o solve this error please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you clear datagridview columns before insert new rows :

```
            this.dgvSampleDetails.Columns.Clear();

private void txtOrder_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
              
                    this.dgvSampleDetails.Columns.Clear();
                    dgvOrderDetails.DataSource = sample.SearchOrders1(txtOrder.Text);
                    dgvSampleDetails.DataSource = sample.GetOrderSamples(txtOrder.Text);
                    btnSave.Enabled = true;
                    dgvSampleDetails.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxselect);
                    checkboxselect.HeaderText = "Select";
                    checkboxselect.Name = "select";

                }
    

}
```

Comment: Thank you its working but when i tried to clear the rows and columns together its give me error unable to clear list so it should be clear columns only anyway thank you .